# How to type an object with AsyncFunction and asyncIterator

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, generator

I have a function that is returning an object like the one below, and I wanted to create a TypeScript interface to type that response but I don't know how to type async functions and iterators

```js
{
  toArray: [AsyncFunction: toArray],
  [Symbol(Symbol.asyncIterator)]: [AsyncGeneratorFunction: [Symbol.asyncIterator]]
}
```

Comment: The types will depend on the types of the parameters (if any) and return types of the functions. Can you edit your question to supply those?

Comment: are you sure its supposed to be `[Symbol(Symbol.asyncIterator)]:`? because `Symbol.asyncIterator` is a symbol, `Symbol(Symbol.asyncIterator)` doesn't make much sense.